# Redirecting from Desktop to Mobile site

Tags: wordpress, redirect, mobile

I'm running a very simple, brochure website on Wordpress and my client needs a mobile website.

I want to redirect mobile visitors from the desktop website to the mobile website. I do not have the technical knowlegde to re-design and re-develop my CMS, so I am planning on making a new subdirectory with mobile-optimized HTML pages and working from there.

Any thoughts on how to make a device-sensitive redirect?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [**Media Queries**](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) ?

In that case you just editing the existing CSS file and don't need to bother with subfolders, mobile detection, redirects etc.

Comment: I know about media queries, but I have a ton of generated content that I'd need to suppress for a mobile friendly site. That said, this article is extremely helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From a simple web search, I turned up this result: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/redirect-mobile-devices/ for a JavaScript implementation. It sets `document.location` to a different url if the width of the screen is less than 699.

Answer (score 1):

I use this PHP statement to check for mobile browsers. I doubt I have all browsers in this function, but it is a start.  You seem to have the know-how to make the basic theme, so this might be the route you're looking to take.

```
if (preg_match("/(mobile|webos|opera mini)/i", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    // Load mobile skin
} else {
    // Load desktop skin
}
```

Comment: If you're going to do browser detection in PHP, there's a lot to be said for `get_browser()` http://php.net/get_browser

Answer (score 1):

I am using mobileesp for php site and it works just right, it appears there is also now javascript available to do the same. Apparently the site has samples.
Hope this helps:

http://blog.mobileesp.com/?cat=8